# Understanding the array of objects

Tags: java

```
TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[2];
shapes[0] = new Triangle("outlined",8.0,12.0);
shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
```

There is a superclass which is TwoDShape and there are subclasses of it.(Triangle , Rectangle vs.) I understand well that superclass reference can refer to subclass object.Yet , I couldn't understand what is happening in the above.Did we create a object which is `shapes` ? I know , arrays are objects.(I'm not sure whether it is relevant or not .. ) Could you explain the logic of these statements ?

Comment: create an array of `TwoDShape` objects and then store objects in it - that is all

Comment: `shapes[0]` refers to an individual _entry_ in the array, which is a `TwoDShape` object.

Comment: There is no real difference between the code you have here and `TwoDShape shapes0 = new Triangle(...); TwoDShape shapes1 = new Rectangle(...);`, in terms of the types and the assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are objects. You created an array object.

The array can hold references to other objects of its type. And when you assign individual elements of the array like this,

```
shapes[0] = new Triangle("outlined",8.0,12.0);
shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
```

the objects are assigned to the allocated index in the array. This is possible because a reference of *Super* Type can hold an object of *Sub* Type.

Here is a [brief tutorial on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

---

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

**TwoDShape** is a superclass it's clear. Now another Triangle and Rectangle are implementation of TwoDShape class.

Thats the reason for we can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have class design similar to this like so the :

```
class TwoDShape {
}

class Triangle extends TwoDShape {

    private String s;
    private double s2;
    private double s3;

    public Triangle(String s, double s2, double s3) {
        this.s = s;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.s3 = s3;
    }
    //getters and setter
}

class Rectangle extends TwoDShape {

    private int s;

    public Rectangle(int s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    //getters and setter
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[5];
        shapes[0] = new Triangle("outlined", 8.0, 12.0);
        shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
    }
}
```

So the Triangle and Rectangle Class extend from the TwoDShape class, for that when you create an Array of type A `TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[5];`, So you can use both objects `Triangle` and `Triangle` in your array.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement `TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[5];` You're saying that please create an empty 5 item placeholder array for TwoDShape objects.

Then this codes:

```
shapes[0] = new Triangle("outlined",8.0,12.0);
shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
```

It instructs that place an instance of TwoDShape objects(In this case, can be TwoDShape, Triangle, and Rectangle) to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You created an array named shapes which is of the type `TwoDShape`. So it can store data of **type** `TwoDShape`.

Then you stored objects of  *super* **type** `TwoDShape` in the array given that `Triangle` and `Rectangle` **inherit** from class `TwoDShape`